# Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine hosted by Hyper-V loses internet connection after installing Shrew Soft VPN Client

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v, ubuntu-14.04

My work configuration is as follows:

- Physical machine:

  - Windows 8.1 Pro Ultrabook
  - Hyper-V
  - Wireless connection to office Wi-Fi
- Virtual machine (hosted by physical)

  - Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Virtual machine connection is provided by an internal switch sharing the physical machine wi-fi connection (http://snag.gy/cNKCY.jpg).

When I try to install Shrew Soft VPN Client on the physical machine, the virtual machine loses its connection to internet: does not ping google, can’t reach dns server (8.8.8.8), can’t do anything outside of it. Despite this lack of connection to the outside world, the physical machine is still able to contact the VM (ping, ssh, etc…).

Anyone has an idea on how I could solve this issue? Please let me know of any diagnostic I can run on physical or virtual machine, if needed.

Thanks in advance,

Claudio

Comment: Do other VPN clients cause this problem?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, i do not tried any other. I need a mutual PSK + XAUTH authentication enabled client, do you know any i can use to test?

Answer (score 1):

1. create an "Internal Network" Virtual Switch for your Ubuntu VM
   (Hyper-V Client)
2. On Host machine, goto "control Panel", "Network
   and Internet", "Network and Sharing Center"
3. Left click on Host
   "connections" (This is the physical wireless adapter)
4. In pop-up
   window, click on properties
5. Click on "Sharing"
6. Check box
   "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's
   Internet Connection
7. Under "Home Networking Connection), select
   name of Virtual Switch you created at step 1.

Should work now. Just FYI, the above steps are NOT necessary if you are creating a Windows VM.

Regards,
Mike